# <img> for directly download image sources

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

Take these two image links as example:

https://img.letgo.com/images/29/90/9d/c0/29909dc07b011e29a1bd21a12cf58117.jpeg?impolicy=img_200

https://img.letgo.com/images/30/d9/07/ee/30d907ee7da5130a16009dd56b9bd808.jpeg?impolicy=img_200

If you try to open the first link in a browser, it will directly prompt you to download. However, if you try the second link, it will render directly in browser tab.

I have two questions here:

1. What caused this difference?
2. I found the first image will not render in `<img src=[image1] />` html tag. Is there a way to render it correctly? (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7poreop/1/)

Thank you!

(Here's a screenshot of what I see from my browser. I'm using Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit))

[image]

Comment: Both displays for me, none downloads

Comment: none of them prompts me to download !

Comment: @HugoRegibo Maybe it only happens in Chrome...?

Comment: @AalindSharma Maybe it only happens in Chrome...?

Comment: @AllanJiang which version of chrome are you using ? I am using 67.0.3371.0  and am unable to see a promt.

Comment: @AalindSharma just updated my question with my Chrome version and a screenshot...

Comment: the behavior is also controlled by the server http header. It might not have any thing to do with your code.

Comment: I'm using the same Chrome version and I can see both pictures in JSFiddle

Comment: Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) => no issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Both images shown normal for now.

But there are can be some reasons for behaviour you see.

One of them is that downloaded image was not in the server, so server try to found replacement for it. It founds another image, send it to you but with headers to download - not to show. (or something like that)